# Problems using GROUP BY and ORDER BY in SQL Oracle

Tags: oracle

So I've been instructed to write a SQL query to display the manager number and the salary of the lowest paid employee for that manager(2 columns within a database I'm working in). I must also exclude any groups where the minimum 
salary is less than or equal to $6,000. Sort the output in descending order of 
salary. Now I've successfully displayed the data however, I cannot seem to order it in descending order which is what brought me here. Currently my code is as follows:

Code Snippet #1

```
SELECT manager_id AS "Manager ID",
MIN(salary) AS "Lowest Paid Salary"
FROM employees
WHERE manager_id IS NOT NULL
AND salary > 6000 
GROUP BY manager_id;
```

Which gives me the following output:
Code Snippet #2

```
Manager ID Lowest Paid Salary
---------- ------------------
       100               6500
       147               6200
       205               8300
       108               6900
       148               6100
       149               6200
       102               9000
       101               6500
       145               7000
       146               7000
```

However, I need these values ordered from Largest -> Smallest salary. I attempted to add a `GROUP BY salary DESC;`  At the end of the statement which would give me the following error: `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`

Upon some research I found that the two (GROUP BY and ORDER BY) cannot be used together in the same query as I did not include both manager_id and salary within the GROUP BY clause. So I attempted that with the following code:

```
SELECT manager_id AS "Manager ID",
MIN(salary) AS "Lowest Paid Salary"
FROM employees
WHERE manager_id IS NOT NULL
AND salary > 6000 
GROUP BY manager_id, salary
ORDER BY salary DESC;
```

Which gives me a list of all the salaries for each manager_id as well as duplicates. This is not what I am looking for.

I apologize for the excess of reading, I just want to make sure you know what I've tried and what I am attempting to accomplish.

So I need to know a way I can either use both the GROUP BY and ORDER BY in the same query to display the Code snippet #2 but have it ordered. Or another way to order this data in the same format.

Thanks in advance for any help/advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to order by the aggregate function. ...
Try this

```
SELECT manager_id AS "Manager ID",
MIN(salary) AS "Lowest Paid Salary"
FROM employees
WHERE manager_id IS NOT NULL
AND salary > 6000 
GROUP BY manager_id
ORDER BY min(salary) DESC;
```

Comment: Gah! Of course something so simple, this worked! Thanks for the help, always in coding it's the tiny detail that seems to pass the eye

Answer (score 6):

You can either sort by the column number or column name

```
SELECT manager_id AS "Manager ID",
MIN(salary) AS "Lowest Paid Salary"
FROM #employees
WHERE manager_id IS NOT NULL
AND salary > 6000 
GROUP BY manager_id
order by 2 desc


SELECT manager_id AS "Manager ID",
MIN(salary) AS "Lowest Paid Salary"
FROM #employees
WHERE manager_id IS NOT NULL
AND salary > 6000 
GROUP BY manager_id
order by "Lowest Paid Salary" desc
```

Comment: you mean column value ?

Comment: Well, of course the sort will be "value" based, the to tell the query to sort by the salary value, is to refer to the salary column, which can be done in the two ways I mentioned: Either by explicit writing the column name which is "Lowest Paid Salary" alias, or it's number as it's the 2nd column returned in the selected statement..

Answer (score 0):

Try: 
order by manager_id ,salary DESC and remove the group by clause
for example 
SELECT * FROM Customers
ORDER BY CustomerID DESC,CustomerName;
This statement will arrange the results according to customer id in desc order.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I tried this and received this error:
`GROUP BY manager_id DESC, salary
                    *
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`